# How to show all files errors in react app with eslint by one line code in scripts in package.json?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

I want it to show all errors for all files in react/next app in command line with eslint when i write (for example) "npm run errors" or "npm run lint".

I tried searching for eslint but couldn't find anything!

Comment: Could you share some more details about the problem? In a React/Next application, you typically use a `package.json` file to define the scripts to run with `npm run <script_name>`, could you share your package.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "lint:check": "eslint ./src --ext .jsx,.js,.ts,.tsx --ignore-path ./.gitignore",
    "lint:fix": "eslint ./src --ext .jsx,.js,.ts,.tsx --quiet --fix --ignore-path ./.gitignore"
}
```

So, you can view all eslint errors/warnings using `npm run lint:check` and fix them using `npm run lint:fix`

You can adjust these commands for your needs, and you will also have to set up the eslint configurations through `.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.json` file to define what eslint errors/warnings to show up or ignore, etc.